# Python vs Stata in data preparation

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I understand it is highly unlikely, but I can't figure out why Python outputs a slightly different dataset after simple manipulations, which I think are identical to those that I do in Stata. 
So, Stata:

```
use "filename", clear  
drop if varname < 1500  
sum
```

### STATA (raw data)

Obs:  610
Mean:  1339.482
Std:   17.27477
Min:   1304
max:  1368

### Checking for missing (`mdesc varname`)

Missing: 10953
Total: 11563
Percent missing: 94.72

### STATA (after `drop if varname < 1500`):

**varname** |**obs**: 389  **mean**: 1350.599 **Std.Dev.**: 9.564949 **Min:** 1333 **Max:** 1368
Type: float

Meanwhile, Python:

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_stata("filename.dta", convert_missing = False)  
df = df[df.varname<1500]  
df.describe()
```

---

**PYTHON (raw data: `df=pd.read_stata("filename.dta")`)**:  varname
Count:  610
Mean:  1339.481934
Std:   17.274755
Min:   1304.000000
25%:  1326.000000
50%:  1341.000000
75%:  1353.000000
max:  1368.000000

`df.isnull().sum()`
varname         10953
So the number of missings in raw data is same in Stata and Python, but after dropping i get two different datasets.

### PYTHON, after `df = df[df.varname<1500]`  ##

Count:  288.000000
Mean:  1325.760376
Std:   13.369122
Min:   1304.000000
25%:     1316.000000
50%:    1325.000000
75%:  1332.000000
max:  1365.000000

In partcular, the differences are in counts of observations. For some variables there is a patterned difference, i.e. Stata: 11 342 obs, Python: 5064 obs (twice as few). For some variables, the difference is not patterned, just different values. The summary statistics are not too different, but different. 
I am new to Python, so can you please share if that is indeed possible that it operates on data differently from Stata?

### Edit:

I figured out that I dropped incorrectly, instead of `df = df[df.varname<1500]`, I should have typed `df_new = df.drop(df[df.varname< 1500].index)`. I dont know the difference, but now I have the dataset that I need. Thanks everyone for spending time here!

Comment: This seems quite unlikely, to be honest. Could you provide type and descriptive statistics on `varname`, both directly after reading in the data and after dropping? My guess is that null values are treated differently.

Comment: Can you include the counts before dropping any observations to verify that the data that is being read in is identical? Also, can you explicitly check for missing values?

Comment: df = df[df.varname>1500] ...?

Comment: @coffeinjunky, it seems like the datasets are same, but they change after I use the df = df[df.varname < 1500] to drop observations less than 1500

Comment: @tianlinhe, yeah after this command I get a dataset different from stata, so probably this is an incorrect line

Comment: @mj_bonbon I explain it a bit in the answer, I hope it is more understandable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you misinterpret the behavior of boolean operation inside the `df[]` clause.

In pandas, the statement inside `df[statement]` must be `True`, so that it can be selected.

In your example,`df = df[df.varname<1500]` will returns what is `True` for `df.varname<1500`. So you will get those rows satisfing `df.varname<1500`, instead of dropping them.

Comment: thank you so much! I figured out my issue, but didn't get the reasoning why one thing works and the other does not. Now thanks to your explanation I understand!

Comment: I am glad to help you too! Would you then accept it as answer or upvote it?

Comment: @tianlinhe, no problem :)